# how to active/deactive a module for each store by admin in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento2.2.2, magento2.3.0

I want to give ability to admin to active or deactive a module for each store.

at previous magento version this option was exist under **store -> configuration -> advanced -> advanced** menue and we could enable or disable a module per store , but from magento 2.2 this option has been removed and no longer avalable.

according [this](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/advanced-menu-missing/td-p/81384) link for this purpose we have to do some setting manually in our module .

I want to make setting in my module that admin can see the list of stores and by selecting them to enable or disable a module . for example admin wants to enable module be active for store A and B , and deactive for store C .

the list of stores should be dynamic and reads from database and shouldn't be hard code.

I don't have any idea how can I do it .Someone can help me figure out how I can do it ? If you could please point this out, I would be really grateful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create admin filed using system.xml, then use that field to whatever the location..

For example..

By using etc/system.xml

```
 <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
      <label>General Configuration</label>
      <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
          <label>Module Enable</label>
          <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
      </field>
 </group>
```

Then get this value in helper class

```
/*
 * @return bool
 */
public function isEnabled($scope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)
{
    return (bool) $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
        'additional_registration_fields/general/enable',
        $scope
    );
}
```

then in block you can use as

```
public function isEnabled()
{
    return $this->helperData->isEnabled();
}
```

& final check on view files of frontend:

```
<?php if ($block->isEnabled()) : ?>
    // code here if module is enabled for current storeview
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thank you for reply , that's good idea , but I want enable or disable  a module for both frontend and adminhtml for specefic stores, and I don't have access to change core magento codes , I want set configuration in my module and these changes apply throughout the store . is there any global variable to hold state of modules in magento that magento checks them for loading modules ?

Comment: Yes, You can enable/disable whole module by using this method too..

Comment: Just add if condition in every controller's execute method like this ...     if ($this->helperData->isEnabled() == 'yes' )  { // your whole code here }

Comment: your were right , just one question , how can I use this if condition for prevent load js files ? . I have requirejs-config file that I load some js files instead of core magento js files , how to load these files conditionally ?.

Comment: Please check this blog.
https://webkul.com/blog/call-configurable-external-js-url-magento2/